# Can i write a grid with more columns without targeting the row columns count size 12 in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

One of my designers coded as below, to show responsive product blocks. Design presenting 3 products in Desktop and 2 products in Tablets.

This Markup showing more than 12 column count in a row. I never seen such kind of structure in Bootstrap documentation or in other sources.  Is this Valid? Do you support this Markup?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">Product</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">Product</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">Product</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">Product</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">Product</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">Product</div>
    ........
    .......
    .......
```

Comment: "if it dose not fit it will simply wrap" so i see no proplem

Answer (score 1):

Each div with the column attributes like `col-md-4`  gets a simple set of CSS properties added to it.
some padding: 
(its a really long line - you need to scroll sideways)
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L814

```
[...] .col-md-4,[ ..] {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

then, above the media query breakpoint, the `float` property is applied
and its width is set
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1207

```
  .col-md-4 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333333%;
  }
```

<sub>because the stylesheet uses `box-sizing: border-box` this `33.33%` is applied to the border - not the content - box (not totally relevant - just a side issue).</sub>

Because the nature of floated elements is to simply stack alongside each other until there is no room, then they drop down into a new line box , this seems like it is fine.
The parent `class="row"` being `display: block;` will have its margin box set to full width of it parents content box.
In this case the columns elements get their widths set to be 1/3 of the parent container, because there are alot more than 3, i.e. the markup is saying *here are some child elements whose aggregated width is 300% of its parent* the row elements fall back to wrapping.
Which is quite a nice effect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this markup is valid. There is an official Bootstrap [example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/) where same layout is used.

Comment: Thanks for the refference.